# Django: Issues with if condition in templates

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement, lang

I want to print something on the basis of the current language code. For that I did something like this:

```
{% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == en %}
    <h1>English</h1>
{% endif %}
```

But this if condition does not compare the current language code.  But if I print this `{{request.LANGUAGE_CODE}}` on the same page then it will print `en` as language code, but my if condition is not working and I don't know why ??

Comment: You can {{ this_variable_does_not_exists }} and it will pass. If you move your test etc to the view it will evaluate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LANGUAGE_CODE is a string, so you just need to enquote your comparison value like this:

```
{% if request.LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
    <h1>English</h1>
{% endif %}
```

check also the [ifequal tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal)

```
{% ifequal request.LANGUAGE_CODE 'en' %}
    ...
{% endifequal %}
```

a bit more: the if and ifequal on strings are case sensitive, so you may want to be sure you're matching the correct case (maybe applying the |lower filter to both arguments)